# get text from an element and store in a variable in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to get text from an element (input tag) and store it in a variable.

The below statement is used to set data in the text field.

```
cy.get('app-screen).find('input[id="studentName"]').type("Viola");
```

Tried with the below statements to get the text:

```
 cy.get('app-screen).find('input[id="studentName"]').then(($text1) => {            
      let textValue1 = $text1.text());
      cy.log('Student Name: ' + textValue1 );                       
    });

cy.get('app-screen).find('input[id="studentName"]').invoke('text').then(text2 => {
  let textValue2 = text2;
  cy.log('Student Name: ' + textValue2 );  
});
```

In both ways the output was empty as below.

```
Student Name:
```

Could anyone please help to sort this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming after the `type` command the typed value gets saved in the `value` attribute. Also, you can use alias to save the inner Text something like:

```js
cy.get('app-screen').find('input[id="studentName"]').invoke('val').as('name')
cy.get('@name').then((name) => {
  cy.log('Student Name: ' + name) //prints name
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it works. In case, if this code is written inside a function and I have to return the student name to the function call then how to use return keyword here?

Comment: Hi @saran since this is a different question, I would suggest you to open a new thread for this,

Comment: I was having problems getting the element value with text(). This method has helped me, as well. thank you!

Comment: The problem with the code in this answer is in TypeScript definitions. Current Cypress type defs say that the "name" variable is a JQuery element (and not e.g. a string). Ugly casting must be done to make the error go away.

Comment: @LubosD Use `cy.get<string>('@name')` for getting it as a `string` type

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to see check how the element stores the text you are viewing in the UI.
NOTE: `.invoke('text')` used the jquery method `.text()` which grab the `textContent` of the element. To get the `innerText` then you'll have to use a callback function.

If you are looking to log out the text value, then you can do one of the following:

```
cy.get('app-screen')
  .find('input[id="studentName"]')
  .invoke('val')
  .then(cy.log) // this will log out the text

cy.get('app-screen')
  .find('input[id="studentName"]')
  .then($el => { cy.log($el[0].innerText }) // this will log out the innerText
```